# Sum of divisor and positive divisor problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The sum of all the **positive divisor** and the **sum** of **their reciprocals** of a number **N** are $195$ and $\frac{65}{24}$ respectively.
**Find N**?

Comment: OK, I found $N$. Now what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose the divisors of $N$ are $1 = d_1 < d_2 < \cdots < d_{m-1} < d_m = N$.

Since the divisors of $N$ come in complementary pairs, we have $d_i = \dfrac{N}{d_{m-i}}$.

The sum of the divisors is $\sigma_1(N) = d_1+ d_2 + \cdots +  d_{m-1} + d_m$.

The sum of the reciprocals of the divisors is $\sigma_{-1}(N) = \dfrac{1}{d_1}+ \dfrac{1}{d_2} + \cdots +  \dfrac{1}{d_{m-1}} + \dfrac{1}{d_m}$.

Then, $N\sigma_{-1}(N) = \dfrac{N}{d_1}+ \dfrac{N}{d_2} + \cdots +  \dfrac{N}{d_{m-1}} + \dfrac{N}{d_m} = d_m + d_{m-1} + \cdots + d_2 + d_1 = \sigma_1(N)$.

Therefore, $N = \dfrac{\sigma_1(N)}{\sigma_{-1}(N)} = \dfrac{195}{\tfrac{65}{24}} = 72$